# How to combine stdin with stdout?

Tags: python, windows-10, stdout, stdin

I am a teacher working on automating student assignment checking and would like the output file generated when I run a student program using `subprocess.run` to look just like it does when I run it manually.

The following program

```
import subprocess
import sys

userInput = open("userInput.txt")

with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
    with open("error.txt", "w") as ferr:
       result = subprocess.run(["python","hello.py"], stdin=userInput,stdout=fout,stderr=ferr)
```

with this **hello.py**

```
name = input("Your name: ")
age = input("Your age: ")
print('Hello,',name,"you are",age,"years old")
```

and this **userInput.txt**

```
Bob
27
```

generates the following **output.txt**

```
Your name: Your age: Hello, Bob you are 27 years old
```

How can I get the program to generate an **output.txt** file that looks the same as when I simply run hello.py (where the stdin also shows up in the stdout).

```
Your name: Bob
Your age: 27
Hello, Bob you are 27 years old
```

I am doing this on a Windows 10 system.

Comment: Which operating system? On Linux you could use `pexpect`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check that you require the input to appear just as it does when input is entered manually?

Comment: I would like to run the student's program and then compare it to the expected golden output using a program like tkdiff that highlights differences.  The tkdiff output would just be easier to look at if the program produced the same output that I get when I just run the program manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a much more complicated task that it seems at first. You are basically trying to monitor the data being read from stdin and written to stdout.

The easy solution is to use the pexpect library.
https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

For example:

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('./hello.py', logfile=open('output.txt', 'wb'))
child.expect('name:')
child.send('Bob\n')
child.expect('age:')
child.send('27\n')
child.expect('H') # Necessary to get the last line of output.
```

The output duplicates the stdin information. I'm not sure why it is doing that.

```
Your name: Bob
Bob
Your age: 27
27
Hello, Bob you are 27 years old
```

If you want to re-implement pexpect yourself, you will need to use `subprocess.Popen()` and write to `p.stdin` and read from `p.stdout` directly.
This will require changing the `p.stdout` to be non-blocking.

```
import os
import fcntl
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['hello.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
flags = fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
while True:
    try:
        out = os.read(p.stdout.fileno(), 100000).decode("utf-8").strip()
        # process output
    except BlockingIOError:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```